# newConditionalFormatRule()が「is not function」エラー

Tags: javascript

newConditionalFormatRule()を実行したいのですが「is not function」エラーでできません。

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#newconditionalformatrule
記載のサンプルコードを丸ごとコピーし

```js
function myfunction(){
  // Adds a conditional format rule to a sheet that causes all cells in range A1:B3 to turn red
  // if they contain a number between 1 and 10.
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange('A1:B3');
  var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule()
      .whenNumberBetween(1, 10)
      .setBackgroundColor("#FF0000")
      .setRanges([range])
      .build()
  var rules = sheet.getConditionalFormatRules();
  rules.push(rule);
  sheet.setConditionalFormatRules(rules); 
}
```

のように関数に入れて実行しようとしたのですが

> TypeError: SpreadsheetApp.newConditionalFormatRule(...).whenNumberBetween(...).setBackgroundColor is not a function（行 8、ファイル「Condition」）

と表示され実行できませんでした。

GASでのis not functionエラーを調べ、
https://qiita.com/UtaMori/items/ce83672cecca20964899
からruntimeVersionがV8になっていないことが原因だと考えられたので
「表示」タブの「マニフェストファイルを表示」を選択し「appscript.json」ファイルを表示しました。

しかしappscript.jsonは

```js
{
  "timeZone": "Asia/Tokyo",
  "dependencies": {
  },
  "exceptionLogging": "STACKDRIVER",
  "runtimeVersion": "V8"
}
```

となっており、`"runtimeVersion": "V8"`なのでこれが原因ではなさそうだとわかりました。

どうすればよいでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そのサンプルは情報が古いようです。今はsetBackgroundColorというメソッドは存在せず、代わりにsetBackgroundを使う必要があります。

- 参考: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/conditional-format-rule-builder#setBackground(String)

Comment: Googleにフィードバックを送っておきました。